# SQL JOIN AND SUB QUERY

Tags: sql

below are two tables **customer information** and second **customer with their loan and repayment** I want to join these two tables and retrieve the expected result in the picture, please note that in the second table one customer can have more than one loan and he/she can repay it in several installments that in the second table that it saved in many rows, I am expecting to join the two tables and retrieve clients who are still owed from the company.

I found the expected result as a good solution for this purpose but could not retrieve the expected result.

and if you have a good solution for my purpose rather than expected result please share.

example:-

[image]

I tried below query but it does not work, because the client id number 1 disbursed three times loan when it shows the tree times purpose it shows that total of the loan three times too

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.ID, 
CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.NAME,
( 
    SELECT SUM (CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.LOAN) AS "Total Loan" 
    FROM CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE 
    WHERE CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.ID = CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.FK_ID
) AS "Loan", 

( 
    SELECT SUM (CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.REPAYMENT) FROM CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE 
    WHERE CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.ID = CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.FK_ID
) AS Repayment , 

CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.PURPOSE 
FROM CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE 
ON CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.ID = CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.FK_ID
```

Comment: please add what you have tried so far to achieve the result?  Add your query here.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv jadia

Comment: just added  ankit suthar

Comment: @AbdulHay Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: That table structure is gonna cause endless headaches because of the poor design. Why are you storing the loans and payments in the same table? Also, FK_ID should be CUSTOMER_ID. I am assuming FK stands for Foreign Key which is highly non-specific. You need to break the loans out into a separate table. This structure breaks if a customer has two loans with the same amount.

Comment: How do you marry `Loan` with `Repayment`?

Comment: @JohnFx I thought that joining many tables is going to decrease query performance, and i named it FK_ the id of the first table because to know this is the not the id of the second table, and this is the id of the first table,

Comment: @Cha , i used sub query for showing them in one row

Comment: If 100% forced to deal with a structure like this you'll do much better with a stored procedure and cursors, they can get you there and will likely be way more maintainable.

Comment: @eyegropram could you plz instruct a bit

Comment: @Abdul Hay - Databases are VERY good at optimizing performance and this will make it worse both for performance and for any poor programmer who has to work with this. Also, that naming convention is terrible unless you expect your entire database will ever only have two fields. Name every column with something meaningful and don't force people who work on this code after you to make assumptions like that. This is egregiously bad. (no offense)

Comment: @JohnFx thanks for your comments, if you plz share a book or any tutorial link so that i could learn more about these issue i would glad alot.

Comment: With this design you will have problems as soon as someone loans the same amount twice... which one was repayed and which one wasn't? You cannot tell. One possibility is to have a single line for each loan/repayment, basically what you have as result.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: am using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Subquery you could use a inner join on select table group by id

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.ID, 
    CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.NAME,
    T.Total_Loan AS "Loan",
    T.Total_Rep AS Repayment, 
    CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.PURPOSE 
FROM CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE 
INNER JOIN (

  SELECT CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.FK_ID as FK_ID,
            SUM (CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.LOAN) AS Total_Loan 
          ,  SUM (CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.REPAYMENT) AS Total_Rep 
      FROM CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE 
      GROUP BY CUSTOMER_AIB_LOAN_TABLE.ID

      ) T on t.FK_ID = CUSTOMER_AIB_INFO_TABLE.ID
```

Comment: Let me try this @scaiseEdge